# setRowFactory issue in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have a problem with my app which uses JavaFX... In one view I have a tableview which contains list of people and I want change row style one person. Here is my code:

```
personTable.setRowFactory(new Callback<TableView<Person>, TableRow<Person>>() {
        @Override
        public TableRow<Person> call(TableView<Person> personTableView) {
            return new TableRowRightFormat();
        }
    });
```

...

```
private class TableRowRightFormat extends TableRow {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Object o, boolean b) {
        super.updateItem(o, b);

        if(o == null) {
            return;
        }

        getStyleClass().remove("headPerson");

        if(((Person)o).getId()==2) {
            getStyleClass().add("headPerson");
        }
    }
}
```

And it is working for one person(id=2) but when I scroll up my table and when person with id=2 disappears another person with id!=2 gets style called 'headPerson' (always one Person on visible elements in tableview has style 'headPerson', but above code is executing once time). What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** I tested your code on both JavaFX 2.2 and JDK 8 and it seemed to work fine for my simple test case. The logic seems right; the one thing you have to be really careful of in these types of style-class based cell and row implementations is making sure you don't add multiple copies of a given string to the list of style classes - in your implementation this looks right. Double check and make sure you have the strings exactly the same in the `add(...)` and `remove(...)` methods.

I like to completely bullet-proof these at a slight cost to performance:

```
private final String headPersonStyleClass = "headPerson" ;

private class TableRowRightFormat extends TableRow<Person> {

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Person p, boolean b) {
        super.updateItem(p, b);

        ObservableList<String> styleClass = getStyleClass();
        if (p != null && p.getId()==2 && (! styleClass.contains(headPersonStyleClass))) {
            styleClass.add(headPersonStyleClass);
        } else {
            // remove all occurrences:
            styleClass.removeAll(Collections.singleton(headPersonStyleClass));
        }

    }
}
```

If you are using JavaFX 8, a better approach is to use a `PseudoClass` for this.